# Sorting Map<Integer,List<Double>>

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

Based on `Map<Integer,List<Double>> dist`, I should create `int[][] indexes` that will store sorted indexes in ascending order, e.g.:

```
dist = 
0, [2.5, 3.5, 8.4]
1, [1.0, 5.0, 6.2]

int[][] indexes =
1,0                  // refers to 1.0 in dist, because it's a smallest value
0,0,                 // refers to 2.5 in dist
0,1,
1,1,
1,2
0,2                  // refers to 8.4 in dist
```

Any idea how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: What have you done so far? And why exactly you want indices? There is no such concept of indices in a `Map`.

Comment: I don't even get the goal...BTW, why is `indexes` a 2d-array?

Comment: Can there be holes in the keys in `dist`? Also, are all List<Double> of equal length?

Comment: @Raffaele Rossi: Because I need to keep a track of original position of the dist value. In this case dist has columns and rows.

Comment: @techG: no, the list is not sorted. but I can sort it. the problem is that I don't know how to create a 2d sorted array based on hashmap.

Comment: I think you need to furnish your question a bit. It sounds like you have a map of lists and want to obtain the result of sorting across both lists. However, rather than actually sort the lists, you want to maintain them in their current state and map the index to indicate the sort order. Is that right? Also, are the lists already in order (as in your example)?

Comment: @wmorrison365: It's right.

Comment: @Klas Lindbäck: Could you please illustrate your idea?

Comment: Are the lists already in order (as in your example)?

Comment: Create a sorted Map (or sorted Set, if you have duplicates) with the value as Key and the position as value. Then you can easily get the position of the i:th value. Looks like Ethan is already in the process of writing a solution for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create a reverse map of `TreeMap<Double,List<IndexClass>>`.

```
 class IndexClass {
       public int row;
       public int column;
 }
```

And the sorting function is like this:

```
 public List<IndexClass> sort(Map<Integer,List<Double>> dist) {
      //Use TreeMap because it will auto sort keys
      TreeMap<Double,List<IndexClass>> treeMap = new TreeMap<Double,List<IndexClass>>();
      for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Double>> entry : dist.entrySet()) {
           List<Double> distValues = entry.getValue();
           for (int i = 0; i < distValues.size(); i++) {
                Double value = distValues.get(i);
                IndexClass index = new IndexClass();
                index.row = entry.getKey();
                index.column = i;
                //There is a duplicate value, simple add the index into the list
                if (treeMap.contains(value) {
                     treeMap.get(value).add(index);
                //It is a new value, so create a list instead
                } else {
                     List<IndexClass> indexList = new ArrayList<IndexClass>();
                     indexList.add(index);
                     treeMap.put(value, indexList.add);
                }
           }
      }
      List<IndexClass> finalList = new ArrayList<IndexClass>();
      //Add all list items together
      for (Map.Entry<Double,List<IndexClass>> entry : treeMap.entrySet()) {
           finalList.addAll(entry.getValue());
      }     
      return finalList;
 }
```

And then you loop through dist and put them into the treeMap.

Then you can print out the values of the treeMap.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I will write a complete example soon.

Comment: Thanks. Just one comment: there might be duplicated in List<Double>

Comment: Also, could you please specify where do you sort List<Double> values?

Comment: Hi, I just updated the answer. So the idea is that we rely on TreeMap to sort the keys for us. And duplicate values will be solved by creating/reusing the List<IndexClass>. Hopefully it is helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Could It be possible.

1. Iterate through structure dist,
2. Create a List of RankedEntry.

   public class RankedEntry implements Comparable{
               Double value;
               int rowIdx;
               int colIdx;

   ```
           public RankedEntry(Double value, int rowIdx, int colIdx) {
               this.value = value;
               this.rowIdx = rowIdx;
               this.colIdx = colIdx;
           }

           @Override
           public int compareTo(Object o) {
               return this.value.compareTo((Double)o);
           }
       }
   ```
3. You do not have a sorted list in java but you can use `Collections` sorting
   methods.
4. Then you can iterate through the This list it will give you
   structure.
5. Fetch rowIdx and colIdx and put them in `int[][] indexes`

Comment: Yes,but how to sort it?

Comment: To remove duplicates you can try TreeSet in Step 2.